# (SQL) Server Agent Job not stopping

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2016, and have some Jobs running in the SQL Server Agent. Today I found one of the job is taking too long (10hours!) to run and is still processing, so I try to stop that. I tried right-click and stop the job, it showed a success message. However, when I go to the Job Activity Monitor, it is showing that the job is still running! I also tried the following code:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'Process Reserving MI (except problematic tables)' 
GO
```

It also says the job stopped successfully. But again when I go to the Job Activity Monitor, it is showing that the job is still running!

Can any one please help?

Comment: Do you refresh the activity monitor after `sp_stop_job`?

Comment: Yes I refreshed the activity monitor each time I tried stopping it, but it is still showing the job is running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sp_stop_job reports Success, but the jobs are still running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/141712/5203)

Comment: Looking through the link, so there is no way to know whether the job is actually stopped or not?

Comment: Look at the active transactions list. Is there something rolling back?

Comment: I tried looking at the open transaction list by: `DBCC OPENTRAN` and it shows "No active open transactions.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I have to ask the server team to reboot the server in order to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where a reoccuring maintenance task (15 minute intervals) was running, would not stop, and could not be run again because it was apparently already running.

My solution was to **restart the SQL Server Agent service for that SQL instance**. The below is a quick guide on how I did it in my environment (Windows Server 2022 running SQL Server Standard 2016)

1. Win + R
2. Run "services.msc"
3. Find service named "SQL Server Agent (*InstanceName*)" where the *InstanceName* is your SQL Server Instance Name.
4. Right Click ther Service
5. Choose "Restart"

This way you're not potentially reboot a production server. Your solution of rebooting the server though did help me formulate this solution.
This forced the unstoppable job to stop, and I was able to execute it manually, and it successfully followed the schedule moving forward.